# asp.net gridview edit template programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is populated programmatically and I later 1 extra column for Edit mode like so:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Add Edit column.
            CommandField cField = new CommandField();
            cField.EditText = "Edit";
            cField.ShowEditButton = true;
            gvCheckResults.Columns.Insert(0, cField);
        }
```

How can I set the attributes of the TextBoxes in the Row which is in Edit mode?

For example, I'd like to disable some textboxes, change the dimensions of others, etc.

Comment: Do you already have the code that puts the Row into Edit Mode when the Edit link is clicked?  Or is that what you need to write?

Comment: Yes I have the gvCheckResults_RowEditing method and the code to update the DB with the new values in gvCheckResults_RowUpdating. I only want to change the attributes of the texboxes that show when clicking Edit. In what section can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've said, above, you might be best served by using templated fields.  Although it's possible to programmatically access the text boxes that are created when a row is put into Edit Mode, you might find it easier to set the textbox attributes in markup.  You can do that with templated fields.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288031.aspx) is a tutorial that explains how it's done.